# How to add configuration button in system.xml file?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I want to add a button in the `system.xml` file that is linked to the google home page in the `system.xml` file.

Comment: You want to display button like this ?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1u0W-xzV6zEwPF7P_OUzEW7yeCb8gYlgL/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: yes and linked it with google home page

Answer (score 3):

You can add these lines in your `system.xml` file here in your custom module

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

You can add field like this..

```
<field id="button" translate="label" type="label" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
    <label>Custom Button</label>
    <frontend_model>Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Form\Field\Button</frontend_model>
</field>
```

You need to create one Block file now here on this path in your custom module

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/System/Config/Form/Field/Button.php

Content for this file is..

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Form\Field;

class Button extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();
        if (!$this->getTemplate()) {
            $this->setTemplate('system/config/fieldset/custom_button.phtml');
        }

        return $this;
    }

    protected function _getElementHtml(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element)
    {
        return $this->_toHtml();
    }
}
```

Now you finally need to create one template file in your custom module here on this path..

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/system/config/fieldset/custom_button.phtml

Content for this file is..

```
<input type="button" name="google_button" id="google_button" value="Google Button">

<script type="text/javascript">  
(function  () {    
    require(["jquery"], function($) {
        $(document).ready(function($) {
            $("#google_button").on("click", function(e){
                window.open('https://www.google.com/', '_blank');
            })
        }); 
    });
})();
</script>
```

Hope this will work for you!

Answer (score 3):

You need to create the `system.xml` file under

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

and use the code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="section_id" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
            <label>Section Label</label>
            <tab>tab_id</tab>
            <group id="group_id" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                <label>Group Label</label>
                <field id="field_id" translate="label" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Field Label</label>
                    <frontend_model>Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Button</frontend_model>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

You need to create the `Button.php` file under

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/System/Config/Button.php

and use the code below:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config;

use Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement;

class Button extends Field
{
    /**
     * Get the button Run
     *
     * @param AbstractElement $element
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getElementHtml(AbstractElement $element)
    {
        $url = "'https://www.google.com'";
        return '<button onclick="location.href=' . $url . '" type="button">' . __('Google') . '</button>';
    }
}
?>
```

Please run below command for display changes :

> php bin/magento cache:flush

Hope this will help you!

Comment: button click is not working .it dispaly sentex error in console

Comment: Answer updated @usman